# Nifi Secure 3 node cluster with signed Certificate

Tags: apache-nifi

I already created 3 node Nifi secured cluster with self signed certificated , where I used nifi-toolkit to do the task. But now I have signed certificate (shared by IT team), the pem and key file. Can you please help (step by step guide) to create 3 node nifi cluster using that certificate?

Step followed:

1. received the signed certificate from IT team
2. convert those to jks format using following command:

   keytool -import -file /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/domainlabs.crt -alias domainCA -keystore /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/truststore.jks

   openssl pkcs12 -export -in /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/domainlabs.crt -inkey /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/domainlabs-SSL-private-2022-23.key -certfile /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/domainlabs.crt -name "examplecert" -out /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/keystore.p12

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /home/nifiadmin/sslcerts-new/keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
3. Used that certificate in nifi.properties
4. the nifi-app.log is showing as below:

   2023-10-05 16:23:52,718 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@54f373d4 checkpointed with 2 Records and 0 Swap Files in 10 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 2 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 1 millis), max Transaction ID 7
   2023-10-05 16:23:53,452 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Successfully deleted 0 files (0 bytes) from archive
   2023-10-05 16:23:53,453 INFO [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Archive cleanup completed for container default; will now allow writing to this container. Bytes used = 27.29 GB, bytes free = 9.11 GB, capacity = 36.4 GB
   2023-10-05 16:23:56,893 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at Server002.domainlabs.com:11443; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
   2023-10-05 16:23:56,893 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.p.AbstractNodeProtocolSender Cluster Coordinator is located at Server002.domainlabs.com:11443. Will send Cluster Connection Request to this address
   2023-10-05 16:23:56,906 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Failed to connect to cluster due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed marshalling 'CONNECTION_REQUEST' protocol message due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
   2023-10-05 16:24:01,913 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at Server002.domainlabs.com:11443; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
   2023-10-05 16:24:01,914 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.p.AbstractNodeProtocolSender Cluster Coordinator is located at Server002.domainlabs.com:11443. Will send Cluster Connection Request to this address
   2023-10-05 16:24:01,932 WARN [Process Cluster Protocol Request-33] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Failed processing protocol message from Server002.domainlabs.com due to Empty server certificate chain
   2023-10-05 16:24:01,934 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Failed to connect to cluster due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed marshalling 'CONNECTION_REQUEST' protocol message due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
   2023-10-05 16:24:06,936 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at Server002.domainlabs.com:11443; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages